# Is it true that $\angle ACK=\angle BCL$ in a circle?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

[image]

Note: this is the core problem I extracted from the following question, which I have been struggling for hours and days and am at the verge of giving up.

[Prove two angles add up to 90 degrees](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3793491/prove-two-angles-add-up-to-90-degrees)

**The problem:**

In a circle, $MN$ is a diameter. $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle such that $AB\perp MN$ and $\angle ACB = 90^{\circ}$. $MA, MB$ intersect the circle at $K, L$. Prove that $\angle ACK=\angle BCL$.

**What I have tried:**

Notice that this problem has a "looser" condition than the original problem, so the statement is not guaranteed to be true $100$ percent. But I have drawn out $5$ different pictures with very high precision and manually compared the two angles, which are always the same. This leads me into believing that this question is the core part of the original problem.

From the given, what I can tell is $A,B,L,K$ are co-cyclic and I did not really go anywhere beyond that despite spending days.

If I draw lines parallel to $AC$ and $BC$ from $M$ and intersect them with the circle, I get a triangle similar to $\triangle ABC$ which pass through the center of the circle, which is nice but unhelpful at all.

The two angles seems so remote. I have a feeling that there is a theorem that can solve this problem in several lines but just that I don't know the theorem.

**The stricter condition:**

If I include one more condition that $KB$ and $LA$ meets the circle at $P,Q$ where $C$ lies on line $PQ$ and $PQ$ is perpendicular to $MN$ then this problem is equivalent to the original problem. But I don't believe that is necessary for this specific result based on experimental observation. (They are necessary for the original problem though)

Comment: By $\angle C$, you mean $\angle ACB$, yes?

Comment: Yes, I will update.

Comment: maybe isogonal -conjugates ..

Comment: Indeed the two lines $CK$ and $CL$ are conjugate of each other but I don't know how to prove.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let's mark intersection of MN and AB as F. Triangles ACF, BCF and ABC are congruent. By angle chasing we can see that:

$BAC=BCN=BCL+LCN=CBM+NMB$

$ABC=ACN=ACK+KCN=CAM+NMA$

Sum the sides of relations you get:

$(BCN+ACN=90^o)=CAM+CBM+AMB$

Now as in figure,MD||AC and ME||BC therefore: $DME=90^o$ that means DE is the diameter of circle and it is parallel with AB. That is triangle DME and ABC are isosceles and points  K and L are mirror about MN ( or CN). hence

$\widehat{ACK}=\widehat{BCL}$

Now the orientation of lines which construct these two angles remain constant, also their measures if triangle MDE rotates about M and base DE rotates about the center of the circle but the measure of angle DME remains at $90^o$. That means if do the reverse procedure, i.e. first draw triangle MDE symmetric about MN, then there can always exist a right triangle like ABC and equal angles  such as ACK and LCB.

Comment: $DE$ is not parallel to $AB$ unless $ABC$ is isosceles. As I mentioned in the question, I tried this approach as well, the resulting triangle $EMD$ is a "flipped" version of $ABC$, where $\angle EDM= \angle ABC$.

Comment: If you try to draw a picture where $AC$ is significantly longer than $AB$, you can see this result pretty clearly.

Comment: @cr001, they are parallel because they are both perpendicular on MN. Also because triangles ABC and MDE have two sides parallel and are both right angled.

Comment: $DE$ is not guaranteed to be perpendicular to $MN$. You can see the picture drawn to precision here where $BC>AC$. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbZvu.png

Comment: Here is a more extreme version. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDaNy.png

Comment: @sirous suggest you delete your answer. BAC is not equal to BCN.

Comment: @cr001, of course they are equal because two rays of them are perpendicular due to statement of question. It seem you are not aware of some elementary theorems of geometry and answering your question is wrong because it goes to endless and pointless arguments. Sorry to say that. by the way you can vote to delet my answer, this is a democratic forum.

Comment: @sirous BAC and BCN are equal. But $BC$ and $AC$ are not equal. I'm not talking about deleting the answer btw, it's someone else. But the flaw in your argument is $DE$ parallel to $AB$. Two diameters do not have to be perpendicular to each other. Please see my picture drawn to precision for $AC\neq BC$ cases.

Comment: In case you are unaware I will post the picture again. Two sides being parallel and the middle angle equal does mean the triangles are similar, but that does not imply the third sides are also parallel. In fact it is indeed the "mirrored similarity" case. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDaNy.png

Comment: @sirous You neglect to say that DE is parallel to AB by design - you select a diameter that is parallel to AB. Than properly define and mark F.  Make N visible. Do you mean F intersect of MN with DE?

Comment: @Moti, there is no limit for th position of  C on MN I guess, so the coincidence of F on center of the circle is a possibility.

Comment: This is a special case. The general case F, intersection of AB and MN, is not the center of the circle.